# XML Sitemap for Media

Tags: media, 7, xml-sitemap

I'm looking for a module, that creates a special sitemap for media (using the Drupal Media 2 module).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Custom sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/custom_sitemap) for achieving this

> The Custom Sitemap module allows users/site admins to add custom
>   sitemaps to a site, unlike currently available module that binds users
>   to build a sitemap using the primary menu.
>
> This module enables you to add or promote random URLs from SEO
>   viewpoint. It also facilitates you to add independent sitemaps for all
>   domains in a multi domain Drupal setup. This also helps you to have a
>   domain specific custom sitemap.

Comment: Will this automagically add the media URLs or do you have to do it manually?

Comment: It has to be done manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XML Sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) for achieving this

For more information about this module you could go through the README.txt of this module.

Comment: Does this integrate with the Media module?

Comment: Well my question is not that clear, I know - so your answer is legit, but it doesn't help, because in the README.txt is nothing about custom sitemaps (or I'm just blind ;) )